# How to write a generic function in Rust that can accept any struct that implements a specific property?

Tags: rust

I am trying to understand generics in Rust and have attempted to write a generic function that can multiple any struct that has the property `foo` by 10. When I use this code, I get the error, `no field foo on type T`.

```
struct A {
    foo: i8,
    bar: String,
}

struct B {
    foo: i8,
}

fn go<T>(v: T) {
    v.foo * 10
}

fn main() {
  let a = A {foo: 1, bar: "bar".to_string()};
  let b = B {foo: 2};
  println!("{:?},{:?}", go(a), go(b))
}
```

How can I write a generic function that can accept any struct that implements a `foo: i8` property?

Comment: you can't cause Rust doesn't have property, use trait

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rust doesn't have properties in the way that JavaScript does, so you need to do things a little differently.  You'll want to use a trait to expose the `foo` functionality as a method, and then implement that trait for `A` and `B`:

```
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self) -> i8;
}

struct A {
    foo: i8,
    bar: String,
}

impl Foo for A {
    fn foo(&self) -> i8 {
        self.foo
    }
}

struct B {
    foo: i8,
}

impl Foo for B {
    fn foo(&self) -> i8 {
        self.foo
    }
}

fn go<T: Foo>(v: T) -> i8 {
    v.foo() * 10
}

fn main() {
    let a = A {
        foo: 1,
        bar: "bar".to_string(),
    };
    let b = B { foo: 2 };
    println!("{:?},{:?}", go(a), go(b))
}
```

(Note that I also made `go` return a value above.)

This provides a `Foo` trait that exposes `foo` as a method, implements it for `A` and `B`, and then makes `go` require `T` to implement `Foo`.  That's the easiest and most straightforward way to accomplish this goal.